# How and where to insert selected rows from DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to transfer selected rows from DataGridView in one form to another.
The questions are: what control is better to use in the second form and how do I transfer my data?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another `DataGridView` would be an apt choice. To transfer the rows, you could use any of these: `DataSet` object, `DataTable` object, a collection, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to transfer data between two pages? Or is it forms?

If you had only `ID` and `Description` as columns, you could then use two **Listboxs** as source and destination.

If you don't want to use the listboxes, then you should do the following:

If it is between controls in same page, then use two **gridviews**, one as source and other as destination. Use **Datatables** to get the rows and insert them in datatables and then put these in **Sessions**. If you need further guidance, let me know.